# Create a new sheet for each unique agent and move all data to each sheet

Tags: vba, excel, move

I have this issue that I'm trying to solve. each day I get an report containing data that I need to send forward. So in order to make it a bit easier I have tried to find a macro that creates a new sheet with the name of the agent and moves the data for each agent  in the created sheet...

I have found one that suppose to do pretty much that. But since this isn't really my area of expertise I'm not able to modify it to handle my request, and even make it work probably. Anyone have any idea ?

```
Const cl& = 2
Const datz& = 1

Dim a As Variant, x As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet
Dim rws&, cls&, p&, i&, ri&, j&
Dim u(), b As Boolean, y

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
rws = Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
cls = Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column

Set x = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("Sheet1"))
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1).Resize(rws, cls).Copy x.Cells(1)
Set a = x.Cells(1).Resize(rws, cls)
a.Sort a(1, cl), 2, Header:=xlYes
a = a.Resize(rws + 1)
p = 2

For i = p To rws + 1
    If a(i, cl) <> a(p, cl) Then
        b = False
        For Each sh In Worksheets
            If sh.Name = a(p, cl) Then b = True: Exit For
        Next
        If Not b Then
            Sheets.Add.Name = a(p, cl)
            With Sheets(a(p, cl))
                x.Cells(1).Resize(, cls).Copy .Cells(1)
                ri = i - p
                x.Cells(p, 1).Resize(ri, cls).Cut .Cells(2, 1)
                .Cells(2, 1).Resize(ri, cls).Sort .Cells(2, datz), Header:=xlNo
                y = .Cells(datz).Resize(ri + 1)
                ReDim u(1 To 2 * ri, 1 To 1)
                For j = 2 To ri
                    u(j, 1) = j
                    If y(j, 1) <> y(j + 1, 1) Then u(j + ri, 1) = j
                Next j
                .Cells(cls + 1).Resize(2 * ri) = u
                .Cells(1).Resize(2 * ri, cls + 1).Sort .Cells(cls + 1), Header:=xlYes
                .Cells(cls + 1).Resize(2 * ri).ClearContents
            End With
        End If
        p = i
    End If
Next i


Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    x.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

This is an example of my report I receive
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xW3r2.png)

[image]

I keep getting error on row: a.Sort a(1, cl), 2, Header:=xlYes 
That in self i don't really know what it does. Can anyone explain?

Comment: So essentially, you just want copies of the original worksheet (renamed for each agent) with all information that is not associated with that agent removed...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a generic model (heavily commented) that should produce your individual agent worksheets. This copies the original 'master' worksheet and removes information that does not pertain to each individual agent.

**[Module1 code](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/create%20a%20new%20sheet%20for%20each%20unique%20agent%20and%20move%20all%20data%20to%20each%20sheet.xlsb)**

```
Option Explicit

Sub agentWorksheets()
    Dim d As Long, agnt As Variant, vAGNTs As Variant, dAGNTs As Object
    Dim wsn As String, wb As Workbook

    'set special application environment
    'appTGGL bTGGL:=False   'uncomment this after debuging is complete
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook '<~~ set to any open workbook or open a closed one
    wsn = "Agents"   '<~~ rename to the right master workbook

    'create the dictionary and
    Set dAGNTs = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dAGNTs.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

    'first the correct workbook
    With wb
        'work with the master worksheet
        With .Worksheets(wsn)
            'get all of the text values from column B
            vAGNTs = .Range(.Cells(6, "B"), .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Value2

            'construct a dictionary of the agents usin unique keys
            For d = LBound(vAGNTs) To UBound(vAGNTs)
                'overwrite method - no check to see if it exists (just want unique list)
                dAGNTs.Item(vAGNTs(d, 1)) = vbNullString
            Next d

        End With

        'loop through the agents' individual worksheets
        'if one does not exist, create it from the master workbook
        For Each agnt In dAGNTs
            'set error control to catch non-existant agent worksheets
            On Error GoTo bm_Need_Agent_WS
            With Worksheets(agnt)
                On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit

                'if an agent worksheet did not exist then
                'one has been created with non-associated data removed
                'perform any additional operations here

                'example: today's date in A1
                .Cells(1, "A") = Date

            End With
        Next agnt

    End With

    'slip past agent worksheet creation
    GoTo bm_Safe_Exit

bm_Need_Agent_WS:
    'basic error control for bad worksheet names, etc.
    On Error GoTo 0
    'copy the master worksheet
    wb.Worksheets(wsn).Copy after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    With wb.Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
        'rename the copy to the agent name
        .Name = StrConv(agnt, vbProperCase)
        'turn off any existing AutoFilter
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        'filter on column for everything that isn't the agent
        With .Range(.Cells(5, "B"), .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
            .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="<>" & agnt
            'step off the header row
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 0)
                'check if there is anything to remove
                If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                    'delete all non-associated information
                    .EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            End With
        End With
        'turn off the AutoFilter we just created
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
    'go back to the thrown error
    Resume

bm_Safe_Exit:
    'reset application environment
    appTGGL

End Sub

'helper sub to set/restore all of the environment settings
Public Sub appTGGL(Optional bTGGL As Boolean = True)
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = bTGGL
        .EnableEvents = bTGGL
        .DisplayAlerts = bTGGL
        .Calculation = IIf(bTGGL, xlCalculationAutomatic, xlCalculationManual)
        .CutCopyMode = False
        .StatusBar = vbNullString
    End With
    Debug.Print Timer
End Sub
```

Sometimes it is just easier to remove what you do not want than recreate many parts of what you started with.

Answer (score 3):

With @Jeeped great answer, I will also add second answer. :-)

To separate each agent data to separate sheets you can do the following... 
see comment on the code

---

```
Option Explicit
Sub Move_Each_Agent_to_Sheet()
'   // Declare your Variables
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim List As Collection
    Dim varValue As Variant
    Dim i As Long

'   // Set your Sheet name
    Set Sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

'   // set your auto-filter,  A6
    With Sht.Range("A6")
        .AutoFilter
    End With

'   // Set your agent Column range # (2) that you want to filter it
    Set Rng = Range(Sht.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(2).Address)

'   // Create a new Collection Object
    Set List = New Collection

'   // Fill Collection with Unique Values
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 2 To Rng.Rows.Count
        List.Add Rng.Cells(i, 1), CStr(Rng.Cells(i, 1))
    Next i

'   // Start looping in through the collection Values
    For Each varValue In List
'       // Filter the Autofilter to macth the current Value
        Rng.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=varValue

'       // Copy the AutoFiltered Range to new Workbook
        Sht.AutoFilter.Range.Copy
        Worksheets.Add.Paste
        ActiveSheet.Name = Left(varValue, 30)
        Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

'   // Loop back to get the next collection Value
    Next varValue

'   // Go back to main Sheet and removed filters
    Sht.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    Sht.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: referring to my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51079283/create-new-tab-and-enter-data-of-the-row-according-to-the-id?noredirect=1#comment89147268_51079283   I tried the code but in every sheet I am getting the first row.