# copy range not finding object

Tags: excel, vba

I have put together a calendar (see image) in excel and one of the features I am trying to work out is how to extract the tasks assigned that day and copy these tasks onto another worksheet.

[image]

I have updated the code to the following

```
Sub OtherTask()
Dim DRng As Range

ActiveSheet.Range("g2:ah2").Find(Date).Select
ActiveCell.Resize(5).Offset(4).Select
Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="1", Operator:=xlFilterValues

'Selection.Copy
'ActiveSheet.Range("r12").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'Application.CutCopyMode = False

    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = "True" Then
        ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = "False"
    End If
```

End Sub

I have declared DRng as the Range but I cannot figure out how to set it so that DRng represents the following

```
ActiveSheet.Range("g2:ah2").Find(Date).Select
ActiveCell.Resize(5).Offset(4).Select
Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="1", Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

The end goal is to have the excel sheet recognise the that day's date - accomplished with the following

```
ActiveSheet.Range("g2:ah2").Find(Date).Select
```

Once the date is established look down the column and filter any cells that have the # "1" in the cell - accomplished with the following

```
ActiveCell.Resize(5).Offset(4).Select
Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="1", Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Once this has occurred I would ideally like excel to then go back towards Column B (I've been trying this will off set and a negative number - no luck) and then copy what is in Column B corresponding to the Row where a "1" is present.  Looking at the image an example would be on February 19th I would like excel to be able to find activity 1A (which is in Cell B7) and copy this cell.

My thinking was that once I was able to locate the day and the cells with a "1" in them I would be able to Set this as the Range DRng and then use DRng to offset over to column B and grab the appropriate cells.  Perhaps (more than likely) I am thinking about this the wrong way as the goal cannot be accomplished with what i have here.  I've been toying with an if statement between With/End With but no luck.  Any ideas/direction is greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: You cannot assign a value to a cell and simultaneously set an objec. Use [AutoFilter method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221844.aspx) to filter for **1** (and possibly a date on anbother column) then [SpecialCells](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) with [xlCellTypeVisible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836534.aspx) to copy all matching results. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36671453/create-a-new-sheet-for-each-unique-agent-and-move-all-data-to-each-sheet/36672632?s=1|0.5378#36672632) for an example.

Comment: With the following I am still getting error 1004

    With ActiveSheet

    .AutoFilterMode = False
    .Range("g6:AH36").AutoFilter Criteria1:=1

    End With

    Dim NewDRng As Range
    Set NewDRng = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    
        Td = Date

        If DRng = Td Then
        
            NewDRng.Copy Destination:=NewSh.Range("a1")
        End If
        Application.Sheets.Add
    End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I'm not sure if I interpret your question correctly since it's a little vague. Do you want to go down the column and grab the corresponding Activity and put them in a new sheet? If so, try this

```
Sub TodaysDate()
Dim DRng As Range
Dim TASKng As Range
Dim newSh As Worksheet

'set the column to loop
col = Range("g2:ah2").Find(Date).column

'create new worksheet
Set newSH = thisworkbook.worksheets.add
tarRow = 1  'set which row to start writing data

For i = 6 to 36     'set which rows to loop
     If activesheet.cells(i,col).value = 1 then
            newSH.cells(tarRow,1) = activesheet.cells(i,1)
            tarRow = tarRow +1
     End if
Next i
```

Comment: Yes that is what I was trying to accomplish.  I've put this into the sheet and though it is adding the new sheet, it is not grabbing the corresponding tasks.   I will work with this though and see if i can get it working.  I do apologise for the vagueness of the question.  Aside from the challenges of understanding/implementing VBA, I find simply asking clear questions a bit of a challenge, but I will keep trying.  I do appreciate the assistance though as it gets me closer to the goal.