# Excel Autofilter, Copy selection, Paste to new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table with source data in columns `Regions!A6:R553`.

In `Regions!A3:R3`, I have formulas that pull specific information out of my data table in `Regions!A6:R553` that I want copied to a different sheet.

Column A acts as my project name column, while column B holds ID numbers. In my case, there are multiple ID numbers per project.

I am looking for a script to filter and loop through all the unique order numbers in Column B one by one, then copy cells `A3:R3` to `RegionsSummary!A12:R12` for as many rows as there are unique order numbers (i.e, add rows to the table).

Here is a screengrab of my data sheet, "Regions":
i.stack.imgur.com/aTPuw.png

Here is a screengrab of the empty template sheet "RegionsSummary":
i.stack.imgur.com/9Ukz5.png

[image]

Example: Assume there are 5 projects in my data sheet. I will filter the data using another macro to select Project_1. I would then like a command button to active a macro that will filter to the first order number in Column B, copy `Regions!A3:R3` to `RegionsSummary!A12:R12`, then filter to the second order number in Project_1, and repeat the process. This should go on until all unique ID numbers have been filtered and looped through.

Here is a screengrab of what a final product should look like:
i.stack.imgur.com/9Ukz5.png

[image]

Here is a link to the file: [Final Output Example](http://www.filedropper.com/highwaytemplate)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36672957/4539709

Comment: Your file link isn't working!

Comment: Why do you need to filter each order number and copy lines individually?  Couldn't you copy from the data rows after applying the Project filter?

Comment: First off, sorry the link is broken! Try this one: http://www.filedropper.com/highwaytemplate_1

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald, Regions!A3:R3 are forumlas that pull specific data out from the data-table specific to each ID number.

Comment: Do I have to install Filedropper? It just takes me to a Google search for Filedropper even if I enter filedropper.com/highwaytemplate_1 in the nav bar.

Comment: you shouldn't have to. click on the link, click "download this file", enter the capcha, and it'll download.

Comment: You can try this download link as well. http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=27736627777873822314

Comment: Here's a more up to date thread on this topic with the written code so far. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42633367/vba-script-loop-broken/42633855?noredirect=1#comment72396498_42633855

Answer (score 0):

I would go with an easier solution than a Macro with certain constraints. I am not able to access your sheet, so I will make a sample excel.

STEPS:

1. Create a list of unique projects for a dropdown (COPY Regions!A5:A10000 to a new sheet > Data > Remove Duplicates) . Create the dropdown (Data Validation > List > Select Range) using Data Validation in "*Example_Result*" sheet- C7.
2. In "Regions", in Col S, put the below formula
   **=S6&"_"&COUNTIF($S$6:S6,S6)**
   Copy this formula down for the entire sheet or as long as you expect the sheet to grow
3. In "*Example_Result*", insert an index column (1 to 1000, in Col A if you expect each project to have 1000 or less order numbers) from A12 onwards.
4. Along the columns (B onwards) of Row 11 include the names of the variables from Regions (Assessment Project, Highway etc).
5. Insert the below formula in B12 to S1000 (depending on number of variables) of *Example_Result*:

**=IFERROR(INDEX(Regions!$A$5:$S$10000,MATCH($C$7&"_"&A$12,Regions!$S$5:$S$10000,0),MATCH(B$11,Regions!$A$5:$H$5,0)),"")**