# Create new worksheets based on values

Tags: vba, excel

I have been trying this for hours and am getting no where. I am using the code below to create new worksheets based on the value in column F. The code creates the worksheet but then copies and pastes the information into the original worksheet, not the new ones. the code is below.

```
Sub RunMe()
For Each cell In Range(Range("F2:"), Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    cell.EntireRow.Copy
    On Error GoTo CreateSheet
    Sheets(cell.Value).Select
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
Next cell

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Exit Sub

CreateSheet:
Worksheets.Add.Name = cell.Value
Resume

End Sub
```

I borrowed it from hours of googling. It creates the sheets, but then they are blank.

please help!

Comment: I posted an answer thinking your `Resume` was a `Resume Next` and then realised it wasn't.  So I tried your code and, apart from the extraneous `:` in `Range("F2:")`, your code worked.  (I dislike the **way** it works, because `Select` statements should be avoided whenever possible, but that doesn't change the fact that it does actually work.)

Comment: Agreed @YowE3K - It could just as easily be `With Sheets(cell.Value)` instead of `Sheets(cell.Value).Select` and the `On Error GoTo CreateSheet` doesn't have to be repeated within the loop since it is not being reset to `On Error GoTo 0` anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

It would help to define the source and destination worksheets. Here is something that I typically would do:

```
Dim source_worksheet As Worksheet
Dim target_worksheet As Worksheet

    Set source_worksheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(" whatever sheet column F is in ex: Sheet1")

    Set target_worksheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(" whatever the new worksheet name is ex: Sheet5")

    source_worksheet.Copy After:=target_worksheet
```

Comment: This is good for the source of the copy but the OP wants to dynamically '*add a new worksheet if one named in column F doesn't exist*'. I've used the on error make new target worksheet with an With statement before but I don't see  how it would be handled here.

Answer (score 1):

In my comments I've stated that it would be easy to switch over to a `With ... End With` that defines the parent worksheet without `.Select` relying on the ActiveSheet property.

```
OPTION EXPLICIT

Sub RunMe()

    dim cell as range
    On Error GoTo CreateSheet

    with worksheets(range("F2").parent.name)    '<~~ name this worksheet PROPERLY!!
        For Each cell In .Range(.cells(2, "F"), .cells(.rows.count, "F").End(xlUp))
            cell.EntireRow.Copy
            with workSheets(cell.Value)
                .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
            end with
        Next cell
    end with

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Exit Sub

CreateSheet:
    Worksheets.Add.Name = cell.Value
    Resume

End Sub
```

FWIW, this is my version of the 'add a new worksheet if the name doesn't exist' process - [Create a new sheet for each unique agent and move all data to each sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36671453/create-a-new-sheet-for-each-unique-agent-and-move-all-data-to-each-sheet/36672632#36672632).