# Excel split sheet data by name into new Excel Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

```
Model   Place
model23 35372
model23 35372
model54 31034
model24 31034
model54 31034
model24 31034
```

I Have this Excel data (the data is bigger is 38000 lines+ I can add all here)
I want try 2 paths..

1)Split the sheets by name model (but I want take and name model and place.

Example:

SheetName: model23

```
 Model    Place
    model23 35372
    model23 35372
```

2)If I can take a range for **place** value from x to y number and split then sheet to this range (example: 30000-40000).

[image]

With green box i want take values and add to a new sheet with model or better if i can make a new Excel file

Comment: Both can be done. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @DavidG I think this is what he is trying to do, White Man see Here 2 examples -  http://stackoverflow.com/a/36672957/4539709

Comment: i want do for every model name create a new sheet and add to sheet the data of this model ... the end result i want to be the bigger data to split to smaller datas (with name of model) ...

Comment: How many models are there? can you also post good example or image of spreadsheet, is it only 2 columns?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/zR43j
With green box i want take values and add to a new sheet with model or better if i can make a new excel file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Try the following, your data will be split into new Excel Workbooks*

*New workbooks will be saved at `CurPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"`*

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Split_Data_NewBooks()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim List As Collection
    Dim ListValue As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim CurPath As String

    CurPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"

'   Set the Sheet Name
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

        If .AutoFilterMode = False Then
            Range("A1").AutoFilter
        End If

        Set Rng = Range(.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).Address)

        Set List = New Collection

        On Error Resume Next
        For i = 2 To Rng.Rows.Count
            List.Add Rng.Cells(i, 1), CStr(Rng.Cells(i, 1))
        Next i
        On Error GoTo 0

        For Each ListValue In List

            Rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=ListValue

    '       // Copy the AutoFiltered Range to new Workbook
            .AutoFilter.Range.Copy
             Workbooks.Add
             ActiveSheet.Paste
             ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=CurPath & Left(ListValue, 30)
             Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
             ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=True

        Next ListValue

        .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Activate
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your reasons for doing this, I would suggest this outcome would not be desirable.

Generally a workbook with too many worksheets is not very functional.

For anyone other than the author of the spreadsheet its far to hard to find what you need.

Not sure what purpose you are doing this for but there will almost certainly be a better design you can implement.

That being said its certainly possible as **0m3r** has linked you.

Comment: Maybe if i make a new excel file ? Thank you for you answer :)