# vba copy and paste rows of data by salesperson into new workbooks by salesperson

Tags: vba, excel

What I have here is a sales report that includes all the sales persons for a date range.

What I need this macro to do is with each salesperson, move their sales to new workbook, save workbook by their number and close.

[Here is what my data looks like and what i want the macro to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdVqa.png)

[image]

I am going to include some code that hasn't been working and that you may not find useful, but it will give you an idea of what im trying to accomplish

```
Public Function ReportSummaries()
 Dim row, col, origPersonsLastRow, origSalesLastRow, i As Integer
 Dim original As Workbook
 Dim cell As Range
 Dim vendorsSheet, RawDataSheet As Worksheet

Set original = Application.Workbooks("SalesReportRpt (7).xlsm")
Set vendorsSheet = original.Worksheets("Sales person")
Set RawDataSheet = original.Worksheets("Sheet1")

'Optimize Macro Speed
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.EnableEvents = False
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
 Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With FldrPicker
  .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
  .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
myPath = myPath
 If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

i = 2
origPersonsLastRow = vendorsSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
origSalesLastRow = RawDataSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
'MsgBox origVeodorsLastRow
For j = 2 To origPersonsLastRow ' cell In vendorsSheet.Columns("A").Cells
    Set cell = vendorsSheet.Cells(j, 1)
    'Set y = Workbooks.Open(" path to destination book ")
    'If cell.Value = 108 Or cell.Value = 30 Then
     '   GoTo NextWB
    'End If
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    With wb
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        RawDataSheet.Range("A1:k1").Copy wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1)
        For k = 2 To origSalesLastRow ' Each rawCell In 
RawDataSheet.Columns("E").Cells
            Set rawCell = RawDataSheet.Cells(k, 4)
            If cell.Value = rawCell.Value And rawCell.Value <> "" And 
 rawCell.Value <> 108 Then
                'MsgBox "Matches"
                rawCell.EntireRow.Copy wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1)
                i = i + 1
            ElseIf i > 6 And cell.Value = "" Then
                'Call BIGreport
                'GoTo Done
            End If
        Next k
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            wb.CheckCompatibility = False
            Do Until Application.CalculationState = xlDone: DoEvents: 
 Loop
            .SaveAs Filename:=myPath & cell.Value, FileFormat:=xlNormal, 
 CreateBackup:=False
            '.Activate
            'wb.Activate
            '.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
            'Call BIGreport(wb)
            .Close SaveChanges:=True
        ElseIf i > 6 Then
          GoTo Done
        End If

    End With
NextWB:

    i = 6
Next j
ResetSettings:
'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
 Application.EnableEvents = True
 Application.DisplayAlerts = True
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Done:
 'Exit Sub
 'Call LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder
 End Function
```

Comment: How isn't it working, do you get errors? If so, what errors, where? If it doesn't give any errors, what is it doing incorrectly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43928128/4539709

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36672957/4539709

Comment: @0m3r your link solved the problem that i was having.. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer offered by @0m3r:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Move_Each_Agent_to_Sheet()
'   // Declare your Variables
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim List As Collection
    Dim varValue As Variant
    Dim i As Long

'      // Set your Sheet name
   Set Sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

'      // set your auto-filter,  A6
  With Sht.Range("A6")
    .AutoFilter
  End With

'   // Set your agent Column range # (2) that you want to filter it
  Set Rng = Range(Sht.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(3).Address)

'   // Create a new Collection Object
  Set List = New Collection

'   // Fill Collection with Unique Values
   On Error Resume Next
   For i = 2 To Rng.Rows.Count
    List.Add Rng.Cells(i, 1), CStr(Rng.Cells(i, 1))
   Next i

'   // Start looping in through the collection Values
  For Each varValue In List
'       // Filter the Autofilter to macth the current Value
    Rng.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=varValue

'       // Copy the AutoFiltered Range to new Workbook
    Sht.AutoFilter.Range.Copy
    Worksheets.Add.Paste
    ActiveSheet.Name = Left(varValue, 30)
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

'   // Loop back to get the next collection Value
   Next varValue

'   // Go back to main Sheet and removed filters
    Sht.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    Sht.Activate
End Sub
```

This solves my biggest problem which was to extract the different salespersons sales...

Answer (score 0):

Since you use Excel for Windows, tap into the JET/ACE Engine and run SQL queries since you essentially are running `WHERE` clauses on master workbook. The only challenge is you have to open two recordsets: one for all distinct *Sales Per* ids to iterate through and each time building the second recordset (applying `WHERE` condition) that dumps data to worksheets. No copy/paste or running through cells with various `If` logic with this approach.

Below is a version tested on both connection types. Be sure to actually change *SheetName* in SQL lines and adjust *Sales Per* to full column name. Even consider moving master data to start at `A1` for a true table. Also, below shows how to parameterize a prepared SQL statement in ADO, an industry best practice when running SQL at application layer like VBA!

```
Sub RunSQL()
    Dim conn As Object, rsSales As Object, rsData As Object, cmd As Object
    Dim strConnection As String, strSales As String, strSQL As String
    Dim new_wb As Workbook
    Dim i As Integer

    Const adcmdText = 1, adInteger = 3, adParamInput = 1

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rsSales = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Set rsData = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    ' CONNECTION STRINGS (TWO VERSIONS)
    strConnection = "DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};" _
                      & "DBQ=C:\Path\To\Master\Data\Workbook.xlsx;"
'    strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" _
'                       & "Data Source=C:\Path\To\Master\Data\Workbook.xlsx';" _
'                       & "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;"";"

    ' OPEN DB CONNECTION
    conn.Open strConnection

    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [SheetName$] WHERE [Sales Per] = ?;"

    strSales = "SELECT DISTINCT [Sales Per] FROM [SheetName$]"
    rsSales.Open strSales, conn

    Do While Not rsSales.EOF
        ' SET CMD COMMAND AND SETTINGS
         Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")    
         With cmd
            .ActiveConnection = conn
            .CommandText = strSQL
            .CommandType = adcmdText
            .CommandTimeout = 15
        End With

        ' BINDING PARAMETER
        cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("salesParam", adInteger, adParamInput, , rsSales![Sales Per])

        ' EXECUTING TO RECORDSET
        Set rsData = cmd.Execute

        ' OPEN NEW WORKBOOK
        Set new_wb = Workbooks.Add()
        ' OUTPUT DATA TO SHEET
        With new_wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
              .Name = "DATA"
              ' COLUMN HEADERS
              For i = 1 To rsData.Fields.Count
                  .Cells(1, i) = rsData.Fields(i - 1).Name
              Next i    
              ' DATA ROWS
              .Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rsData
        End With

        ' SAVE WORKBOOK
        new_wb.SaveAs "C:\Path\To\Output\Workbooks\SalesPer_" & rsSales![Sales Per] & ".xlsx", xlWorkbookDefault
        new_wb.Close True

        rsData.Close
        rsSales.MoveNext
    Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Successfully completed!", vbInformation

ExitHandle:
    rsSales.Close: conn.Close
    Set rsSales = Nothing: Set rsData = Nothing
    Set cmd = Nothing: Set conn = Nothing
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

*Needless to say, consider saving master workbook in a true database and run all the queries to slice and dice as you need.*

Answer (score 0):

*To move the sales to new workbook save it by their number and close, Change the following*

```
Sht.AutoFilter.Range.Copy
Worksheets.Add.Paste
ActiveSheet.Name = Left(varValue, 30)
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

*With*

```
Sht.AutoFilter.Range.Copy
Workbooks.Add
ActiveSheet.Paste

Dim CurPath As String
CurPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=CurPath & Left(ListValue, 30)
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=True
```