# Object variable not set (Error 91)

Tags: vba, excel

I am fairly new to the world of VBA and have been tasked with writing some code which will step through the company names which live in Column A and when that name is found, the code copies and pastes the relevant rows into a newly created workbook. It should then continue onto the next name and so on. During testing the code worked but I have gone into today and I am now getting the object variable error on the line rngG.Select

Can anyone possibly help as I have been looking at this for an hour and it is utterly baffling me now?

```
Sub CrystalUtilitesLtd()


Dim Wk As Workbook
Dim c As Range
Dim rngG As Range

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each c In Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Columns("a"))
    If c = "3rd Party - Crystal Utilities Ltd" Then
        If rngG Is Nothing Then Set rngG = c.EntireRow
        Set rngG = Union(rngG, c.EntireRow)
    End If
Next c
rngG.Select
Selection.Copy

Workbooks.Open "I:\Data\OMR8293\General\Ops Team\Customer Transfer Team\TPI Registration Reporting\TPI Registration Data Template1.xlsx"
Range("A2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("A1:AG1").EntireColumn.AutoFit
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("I:\Data\OMR8293\General\Ops Team\Customer Transfer Team\TPI Registration Reporting\Crystal Utilities Ltd\Registrations_1010112503_" _
                        & Format(Now(), "YYYYMMDD") & ".xlsx")
ActiveWorkbook.Close

Call EnergyAnalystUK

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Why `Select` it anyways? Do you still get the error if you do `rnG.Copy`?  Also you can skip the `.Copy` by setting the two ranges' equal to eachother. Set the `.Open` workbook to a variable, say `newWB` and try `newWB.Range("A2").EntireRow.Value = rngG.Value`.  Note that you're *always* going to `Set rngG = c.EntireRow` since `rngG` is nothing when it runs, and so what are you trying to do with the `Set rngG = Union(rngG, c.entireRow)`?

Comment: You may be interested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36671453/create-a-new-sheet-for-each-unique-agent-and-move-all-data-to-each-sheet/36672632#36672632).

Comment: Have you stepped through the code to ensure that `rngG` is not `Nothing?  There are circumstances where `rngG` is not assigned, so you either need to handle that with an `Exit` statement or move all the dependent code within the `If c = "3rd Party -...` block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the following two lines of code...

```
rngG.Select
Selection.Copy
```

With these lines

```
If Not rngG Is Nothing Then
    rngG.Copy
Else
    MsgBox "No range to copy.", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
End If
```

The reason being that *if* `c <> "3rd Party - Crystal Utilities Ltd"` then the `rngG` object is never assigned a range, so it remains `Nothing`, and since you can't do `Nothing.Select` you'll get an *Object Variable or With Block Not Set* error.

With the above changes, your complete code would be like this...

```
Sub CrystalUtilitesLtd()


Dim Wk As Workbook
Dim c As Range
Dim rngG As Range

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each c In Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Columns("a"))
    If LCase(VBA.Trim(c)) = "3rd party - crystal utilities ltd" Then
        If rngG Is Nothing Then Set rngG = c.EntireRow
        Set rngG = Union(rngG, c.EntireRow)
    End If
Next c

If Not rngG Is Nothing Then
    rngG.Copy
    Workbooks.Open "I:\Data\OMR8293\General\Ops Team\Customer Transfer Team\TPI Registration Reporting\TPI Registration Data Template1.xlsx"
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Range("A1:AG1").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("I:\Data\OMR8293\General\Ops Team\Customer Transfer Team\TPI Registration Reporting\Crystal Utilities Ltd\Registrations_1010112503_" _
                            & Format(Now(), "YYYYMMDD") & ".xlsx")
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
Else
    MsgBox "No range to copy.", vbExclamation
End If

Call EnergyAnalystUK

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help guys, I have replaced the lines of code as you suggested but now when I execute the query, I instantly get a message saying 'No range to copy' when I can see Crystal utilities Ltd clearly as the first row of data. Any suggestions?

Comment: The statement If c = "3rd Party - Crystal Utilities Ltd" Then is case sensitive. Make sure there is no leading or trailing spaces in the cell. Or you can replace that statement with:  If lcase(vba.Trim(c)) = "3rd party - crystal utilities ltd" Then

Comment: I still get the same issue when I replace the statement with your suggestion. When I step through, the sub routine stops after the MsgBox comes up... and doesn't call the next routine Energy Analyst UK... Any ideas?

Comment: Okay I have added the changed code in the solution. Let me know if that works now.

Comment: I have updated my query with your suggestions but now it seems to not pick up any of the company names so I just get pop up boxes with no range to copy....

Comment: I have just noticed something peculiar, if I revert back to my original code and execute it from within the VBE then the query works but if I add a form button then that is what causes the query to fail. Am I better off using activeX controls? I need some form of a button so that is user friendly for other users.

Comment: While you add an ActiveX control and assign code to it, the code is run from that sheet i.e. that particular sheet will be considered as an activesheet in the code. Make sure all the range references you are using in the code belongs to that sheet only. If not, declare a sheet variable and qualify all the ranges with the sheet reference.