# Excel VBA - apply advanced filter and then copy data to another workbook

Tags: vba

I need to apply the advanced filter in VBA and then copy data to another workbook.

I am trying to do this by

```
ActiveSheet.Range("D:D").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Workbooks("E-17-0308_Ubersicht").Sheets("List1").Range("A3"), Unique:=True
```

But it does not work and I probably have an error in the parameter CopyToRange.

Can you help me?

Thanks

Vaclav

Comment: Maybe this is what your trying to do? - https://stackoverflow.com/a/36672957/4539709

Comment: `it does not work` is not a description of a problem. please be more specific

Comment: I get error message "The extract range has a missing or illegal field name".

Comment: I think that the error is in CopyToRange:=Workbooks("E-17-0308_Ubersicht").Sheets("List1").Range("A3"), Unique:=True . I don't know how to address the cell in another workbook correctly.

Comment: I solved this by putting the filter result to the same sheet and then making a copy from this sheet to the new file.