# VBA to Copy and Paste Based on Two Criterias

Tags: vba, excel

It's is possible to create a macro that do a mathematical sum?
I don't know how to explain. But I already saw another answers but I could not make work for me.

Here is what I trying to do:

I have this Worksheet

iTEM 1  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7vXF.jpg

And I to put values as the image below. Make a search and make a mathematical sum in the "available" according with the group.

ITEM 2  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQnxu.png

Here would be the result:

ITEM 3  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ify7J.png

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36672957/4539709

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, tongue in cheek, Excel is very good at doing mathematical sums, and with the help of VBA it gains versatility. To prove the point, the code below doesn't only act upon your selection in the 'Update' sheet, it takes all the items in the 'Update' sheet and posts them to the 'Database' sheet. Click twice and it's done twice over. There is no break.

```
Option Explicit

    Enum Nup                                    ' Sheet Update
        NupFirstDataRow = 2
        NupName = 1                             ' 1 = column A
        NupGroup = 5
        NupQty = 7
    End Enum

    Enum Ndt                                    ' Sheet Data
        NdtFirstDataRow = 2
        NdtName = 1                             ' 1 = column A
        NdtGroup = 3
        NdtQty                                  ' = 4
        NdtOffset = 3                           ' NdtGroup + NdtOffset = Group2 column
    End Enum


Sub UpdateQuantity()
    ' 09 Jan 2018

    Dim WsUpdate As Worksheet                   ' Sheet where data are entered
    Dim WsData As Worksheet                     ' Sheet where data are updated
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim SearchRng As Range
    Dim Itm As String                           ' an item's name
    Dim Qty As Long                             ' Update quantity (designed for integers)
    Dim Rt As Long                              ' target row in WsData
    Dim Rl As Long                              ' last row in WsUpdate
    Dim ClmOffset As Long                       ' helper
    Dim R As Long                               ' row counter in WsUpdate
    Dim Ct As Ndt                               ' column in WsData

    Set WsUpdate = Worksheets("Update")
    Set WsData = Worksheets("Database")

    With WsData
        Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, NupName).End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = Range(.Cells(NdtFirstDataRow, NdtName), .Cells(Rl, NdtQty + NdtOffset))
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With WsUpdate
        Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, NupName).End(xlUp).Row
        For R = NupFirstDataRow To Rl
            Itm = .Cells(R, NupName).Value
            Set SearchRng = Range(Rng.Columns(NdtName), Rng.Columns(NdtName))
            If CellAddress(Itm, SearchRng, Rt) Then
                Itm = .Cells(R, NupGroup).Value
                With WsData
                    Set SearchRng = Range(.Cells(R, NdtGroup), .Cells(R, NdtGroup + NdtOffset))
                End With
                If CellAddress(Itm, SearchRng, Ct) Then
                    Qty = Val(.Cells(R, NupQty).Value)
                    With WsData.Cells(Rt, Ct + 1)
                        Qty = Val(.Value) + Qty
                        .Value = Qty
                    End With
                End If
            End If
        Next R
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Function CellAddress(ByVal Itm As String, _
                             SearchRange As Range, _
                             Rc As Long) As Boolean
    ' 09 Jan 2018
    ' Rc is a return variable (either column or row = 0 if not found)

    Dim ClmRng As Range
    Dim Fnd As Range
    Dim i As Long

    With SearchRange
        Set Fnd = .Find(What:=Itm, After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
        If Fnd Is Nothing Then
            Rc = 0
            MsgBox "Item """ & Itm & """ wasn't found.", _
                   vbInformation, "Update failed"
        Else
            Rc = IIf(.Rows.Count > 1, Fnd.Row, Fnd.Column)
            CellAddress = True
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

The enumerations at the top of the code control which columns and rows are used. You can modify these numbers. Observe that the quantity columns in the Database must be adjacent to the Group columns. The only other place in the code you may have to change concerns the names of the two worksheets. The code must be in a standard code module in the same workbook.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked!! I don't know how to thank you enough! Thanks! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your enthusiasm. I'm glad I could help.