# Creating and Save multiple sheets based on single Range Values

Tags: vba, excel

I am using Excel to split a sheet like the following into multiple sheets based on Client's name:

[image: Please click to see image]

```
Client  Plan    Toal
A       Master   189,50 
A       Master   289,50 
B       Master   239,50 
B       Master   189,50 
B       Master   339,50 
C       Master   239,50 
D       Master   189,50 
E      Master    239,50
```

So, in the example above, I need to automatically create 5 worksheets for each client. I know how to write this using filter criteria (criteria1 = "A", criteria2 = "B"), the problem is: the file above could contain 'n' different clients, so I can't use fixed criterias. I guess I need a for each structure or while but have no clue on how to do this. Could anyone please help me on this topic?

Thanks all!

Comment: So to be clear; you need a list of all the Unique client names in column A?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36672957/4539709

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of to do this is to generate a list of the unique members of column A. You don't specify if you'll always have the same number of items in column A, but I'll assume you want to start at A2 and continue until you reach a blank cell. Then you can loop through them thus:

```
'This stores your unique values
Dim Unique As New Collection
'This variable represents each cell in column A
Dim cll As Range

'If a reference already exists, it will throw an error and jump to the next cell
On Error Resume Next

'Starting at A2 since you don't want to include the heading
For Each cll In Range("A2:A1048576")
    'Exits if there's no name in the cell
    If cll.value = "" Then Exit For
    'Otherwise, add the cell value to your collection
    Unique.Add cll.Value
Next cll

'Turn error handling off
On Error GoTo 0
'Loop through your unique names
For Each Item In Unique
    '<Your code to create a worksheet goes here. "Item" contains each name
    'in the Unique collection>
Next Item
```

Comment: Thanks! Think know i'm able to handle the collectiontp get the multiple sheets!