# VBA copy range after autofilter

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to copy the table after autofilter function works as below code. I try several ways but did not work. How can I filter the only visible cells(table) after autofilter ?

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$K$9:$K$1000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Hatalı", Operator:=xlAnd
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]!  Check out [mcve], and if the answer below does not solve your problem, please **share your code** illustrating the "several ways" that you have tried and also please **define *"did not work"***

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36672957/4539709

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Range.SpecialCells Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-specialcells-method-excel) to get only visible cells in a range.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$K$9:$K$1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Worksheets("destination").Range("A1")
```

Note: this will throw an error if no cells are visible in this range. So you might want to check that first before you copy.

```
Dim FilteredRange As Range

On Error Resume Next 'disable error reporting, below line throws an error if no cells are visible in that range
Set FilteredRange = ActiveSheet.Range("$K$9:$K$1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error GoTo 0 'enable error reporting

If Not FilteredRange Is Nothing Then
    'copy filtererd range if there are visible cells
    FilteredRange.Copy Worksheets("destination").Range("A1")
Else
    MsgBox "The filtered range is empty"
End If
```

Comment: But I need to use also autofilter function,should I write this code after my code ?

Comment: Yes, first filter then select the visible cells from the filtered range with the code above.

Comment: It does not work unfortunately it was only copy the A1. I need to copy all of the columns after the autofilter result

Comment: Because you filter only column K `Range("$K$9:$K$1000")` this only copies column K